# customized command

Tags: macros, tikz-node

first of all, the codes below are just trials. They are far  from perfect.
I have this portion of code that I want to transform into a command for simplicity because I need it very often:

```
\tikzmarknode{c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{teacher.png}}
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{
    \node[name=el,overlay,ellipse callout,fill=blue!20,draw=black,align=center,callout 
relative pointer={(1,0)},left =of c,inner xsep=3 mm, inner ysep=1 mm] at 
([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-0.5cm]c)
{foo\\ bar};
```

Here is my code (I want the command \teacher to have 2 optional paramters, inner xsep and inner ysep, that have the values 3mm and 1mm by default, and the 3rd parameter is the text inside the node).

```
\newcommand{\teacher}[3][3]{\hfill \tikzmarknode{c}{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{teacher.png}}
\tikz[remember picture,baseline]{
        \node[name=el,overlay,ellipse callout,fill=blue!20,draw=black,align=center,callout relative pointer={(1,0)},left =of c,inner xsep=#1 mm, inner ysep=#2 mm] at ([xshift=-1cm,yshift=-0.5cm]c)
{#3};}\\      }
```

`[3][3]` in the first line are probably false, but what I mean is there are 3 parameters (again, the first 2 are optional), and I initialize the first optional by 3 (I would have added [1] after that, to initialize the second optional parameter, inner ysep, but it generates errors).

When I want to call it, the only way that works is this (yes, with just [).

```
\teacher[5][{foo\\ bar}
```

Can someone help me correct my command definition?
Thanks

Comment: you can't declare a command with 2 optional arguments using `\newcommand` you could declare it in other ways but it is usually a bad idea as you can not use the second if you omit the first `\teacher[5pt]{aa}` you can set x but not y

Comment: this answers my question, thank you!